# Outputting Object Properties to Console

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

I have the following object:

```
var myObj={
    
        "name": "Chatik",
        "type": "public_supergroup",
        "id": 9947542893,
        "messages": [
         {
          "id": 1,
          "type": "service",
          "date": "2019-11-11T21:45:33",
          "actor": "Chatik",
          "actor_id": 9947542893,
          "action": "migrate_from_group",
          "title": "Chatik",
          "text": ""
         },
         {
          "id": 2,
          "type": "message",
          "date": "2019-11-11T21:51:22",
          "from": "Korney Chukovsky",
          "from_id": 4528246494,
          "text": "Чому никто не вкатывается?"
         },
         {
          "id": 3,
          "type": "message",
          "date": "2019-11-11T21:55:13",
          "from": "Korney Chukovsky",
          "from_id": 4528246494,
          "text": "Бля, я даже в своей собственной конфе один."
         },
         {
           "id": 7,
           "type": "message",
           "date": "2019-11-11T22:05:48",
           "from": "Андрей",
           "from_id": 4855779304,
           "text": "ты откуда?"
               }
        ]};
```

How do I create a script that would output all "text properties from each "elements" within the curly braces **but** only if the "from_id" property matches a certain value?

For example if my "from id" value is 4528246494, then "text" value should be outputted to the console, then proceed to check the next "element", if the value is not 4528246494, then skip, etc.

Comment: `myObj.messages[1].text`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to access message and grab the second element as normal property accessing

```js
var myObj = {
  "name": "Chatik",
  "type": "public_supergroup",
  "id": 9947542893,
  "messages": [{
      "id": 1,
      "type": "service",
      "date": "2019-11-11T21:45:33",
      "actor": "Chatik",
      "actor_id": 9947542893,
      "action": "migrate_from_group",
      "title": "Chatik",
      "text": ""
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2019-11-11T21:51:22",
      "from": "Korney Chukovsky",
      "from_id": 4528246494,
      "text": "Чому никто не вкатывается?"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "type": "message",
      "date": "2019-11-11T21:55:13",
      "from": "Korney Chukovsky",
      "from_id": 4528246494,
      "text": "Бля, я даже в своей собственной конфе один."
    }
  ]
};

console.log(myObj.messages[1].text)
```

Comment: Ok, nice and how do I iterate to output all of the text attributes from entire object?

Comment: @SSJ5Broli try `forEach`: `myObj.messages.forEach(message => { console.log(message.text) })`

Comment: Thank you! And how do I make the output concatenated into a single string as opposed to being output via separate line?

Comment: And as a bonus, lets say I want to output the text property if the "from_id" matches the certain value?